# Graphics2D text and point position

Tags: java, graphics

I'm getting a strange behaviour when drawing in a Graphics2D.

After draw a line starting at X, Y I draw a circle with center at the same X,Y but the image is not at same position.

[image]

This is the code:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImageData = new BufferedImage(HGT_ROW_LENGTH, HGT_ROW_LENGTH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2Data = bufferedImageData.createGraphics();
g2Data.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
g2Data.fillRect(0, 0, HGT_ROW_LENGTH, HGT_ROW_LENGTH);      
g2Data.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

Font font = new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 20);
g2Data.setFont( font );
g2Data.setColor( new Color(216, 15, 15) );          

int theValue = "1222";

g2Data.drawLine( X, Y, X , Y - theValue );
Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(X, Y, 50, 50);
g2Data.fill(circle);

String s = String.valueOf( theValue );
g2Data.drawString( s, X, Y );
```

I think the line must start at circle center.

Comment: What GIS Software are you using?

Comment: This code is in Java. Sorry, wrong place to ask. Can someone move this to SO ?

Comment: `Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(X, Y, 50, 50);` X, Y here is the top right corner of the bounding square of the circle, not the center of the circle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.Double.html#Ellipse2D.Double(double,%20double,%20double,%20double)

Comment: Uh. It is clear now. But does not make sense.